# Running Total at Opportunity Level

Tags: community, workflow, formula

I've a roll up summary field at the Account level call "Total Revenue".  It rolls up summary of "Revenue" at the opportunity level.  I have a request to show total revenue for each opportunity entered.  I guess it's a running total of revenue.  This field should be static when a new opportunity is created.

Account Level:  Total Revenue = 100

Opportunity Level:

Opportunity 1:  Revenue = 50    **Running Total: 50**
Opportunity 2: Revenue = 25     **Running Total: 75**
Opportunity 3: Revenue = 25     **Running Total: 100**

I'm thinking workflow.  Can someone walk me thru the setup of the workflow to make this works?

Thanks,

Comment: Opportunity isn't revenue. It's the potential to make a sale to create revenue. Depending on how your org uses opportunities, there can also be many child opportunities under a "master" opportunity. A roll-up trigger may be a more appropriate solution to what you've been asked to do. At a minimum, you'd want a roll-up summary field. If you have children and grandchildren, you'll want a trigger. Its not nearly as straightforward as it might appear on the surface with opportunity products, distributor & partner discounts, opportunity shares, and much more involved to involved to get an opp cost.

Comment: @crmprogdev I think I have miss labeled it.  It should be Total Forecasted Revenue.  But thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Not a problem, we all do that at times. I'd trip over my own tongue if it weren't already stuck in my mouth. ;) Hope I've helped to point you in the right direction. In essence, in order to forecast the revenue, you'll need to figure out your opportunity cost first. In my experience, that's the most challenging part of the equation in most orgs. That will also change as line items are added and could vary from quote to quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by adding a formula field to your opportunity to pull in the summary on Account and Amount.

First you will need to configure the Roll-up Summary:

[image: Roll-Up Summary]

You have the option to only include certain opportunities with the summary. This can help if you want to omit certain deals from the running total. In the image, I've limited the summary to opportunities where Stage = 'Closed Won'

Then just add a formula field on Opportunity to pull the Running Total in from account.

```
Account.Running_Total__c
```